# How do I escape Regex to search on a period?

Tags: regex, powershell-2.0, regex-negation

have a simple assignment that's been messing with me and I need another few sets of eyes. I'm sure I'm missing something simple. We have a directory of files that include all kinds of special characters, and I need to strip those out leaving only alpha, numeric, dot (period) and underscore characters. I'm using regex within a PowerShell v2.0 script.

For example:

`!foo12.log` becomes `foo12.log`

`foo1(bar)2.log` becomes `foo1bar2.log`

`[foo]bar_.log` becomes `foobar_.log`

My strategy is to use and exclude list and replace everything else with `""`. Consider:

```
$bkpPath = "\\Server\foo"
gci $bkpPath | %  {$_.name -replace "[^a-zA-z_0-9]",""}
```

When I ran this, I ended up with `foo12log`, `foo1bar2log` and `foobar_log` so I change the regex to include `.`: `[^a-zA-Z_\.0-9]`. That doesn't remove **any** special characters. I've also tried `[^a-zA-Z_\[\]\(\)\.0-9]` with the same results as when I escape a period.

I suspect that there's and issue with my escape to the period `\.` and regex is reading it as a wildcard. If that's what's going on, how do I fix it? If that's not what's going on, what am I missing?

Comment: have you tried `[^a-zA-Z_.0-9]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "." means "anything", it would be silly to use that special character inside square brackets. So in this case, the full stop loses its special meaning and you don't have to use the "\" escape character before it.

Also, it's worth noting that:

\w means "any word character" (letter, number, underscore)

\W means "any non-word character" (Although this isn't a time-saver in this case, since you want to match full stops too.)

So in this case, your relevant bit of regex could just be:

[^\w.]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape a period inside a character class:

```
[^a-zA-Z_.0-9]
```

should work fine. If it doesn't, there may be something special about the powershell regex flavour.